# Stripe subscription upgrade/downgrade change date of a customer

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

I am struggling to find the exact date of subscription upgrade/downgrade changes date of a customer using API. I use Stripe pricing table and allow customers update their plan using customer portal. I can see the current plan and price data but couldn't locate the actual subscription change dates of a customer.

webhooks are ok but since webhooks can be missed I need to be able to query the subscription changes of a customer periodically. Let's say a customer created a subscription and 5 days later updated to another tier. How can I query this second tier change date? Invoices seems to be a way but they are not exactly pointing the subscription change dates. I am using Go library but it doesn't seem to be issue. I couldn't find what I am looking for through the API requests either.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'webhooks can be missed'? The recommendation is that you build a durable webhook endpoint that can handle events that notify you of such async activity.

Comment: @JonathanSteele I mean I receive and handle the Stripe webhook calls for the customer updates. But stripe webhooks are not guaranteed to receive always, what I meant. My application can have outage or due to a network issue webhooks can be missed.

Comment: We'll automatically attempt to [redeliver events](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#retries) in the situation where your endpoint is unreachable. Webhooks are essentially to any Billing integration and we recommend you implement and rely on them.
In any case, when a subscription is upgraded/downgraded via the portal it will trigger a new billing period starting at the time of the upgrade. This can be tracked against the [`current_period_start` field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-current_period_start).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. Well, actually I tested the current_period_start and it doesn't return the subscription tier change value but the actual subscription's start. I examined all the created and start values. I will make sure utilizing webhooks carefully. But if you ask me this is a missing feature in Stripe subscriptions. I have been searching for the options and looks like Events API is suitable for this.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment this but code block doesn't look beautiful. Looks like Stripe Event API can be useful for this. Code example in Golang would be like this to iterate in the events.

```
            eventParams := &stripe.EventListParams{
                Type: stripe.String("subscription.updated"),
                CreatedRange: &stripe.RangeQueryParams{
                    GreaterThanOrEqual: <lastQueryDate>,
                },
            }
            events := event.List(eventParams)
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but keep in mind this will only return events generated in the past 30 days as per Stripe's retention policy https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list

Comment: You're right, thanks for the notice.